# How can I answer vector on the triangle

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, triangles, vector-fields

[image]

> How can I get the vector OP to be this form :

[image]

> I think that

- OP = b + t
- OP = a + s

I do not know how to do this problem, can anyone gives any idea and some steps to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your definition of s and t, from triangle OAN we have

$$\vec{OP} = (1 - s)\vec{OA} + s\vec{ON} = (1 - s)\vec{a} + \frac{1}{3}s\vec{b}$$

Hence A = 1, B = 1 and C = 3.

Also from triangle OBM we have

$$\vec{OP} = t\vec{OM} + (1 - t)\vec{OB} = \frac{3}{4}t\vec{a} + (1 - t)\vec{b}$$

Hence D = 3, E = 4 and F = 1.

By comparing these 2 equations, we have

$1 - s = \frac{3}{4}t$ and $\frac{s}{3} = 1 - t$

The solution is $s = \frac{1}{3}$ and $t = \frac{8}{9}$

Therefore $\vec{OP} = \frac{2}{3}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{9}\vec{b}$

Comment: Oh I get more insights, thxu, but I am confused bcs the right answer is : s= 1/3 and t = 8/9

Comment: And I wonder how is the PN. OA looks like and how can you get them ?

Comment: Sorry to have made a mistake by missing an 's' in the first equation.  Now is fixed as shown above.

Comment: Oh alright thanks, but can you give more explanation about what PN x OA looks like ?

Comment: PN = (1-s)AN =(1-s)(AO+ON) = (1-s)(-a+b/3)=-2a/3+2b/9  Also OA=a

Comment: Therefore PNxOA = (-2a/3+2b/9).a = -2/3+2/9b.a = -2/3+2/9(length of OA x length of OB x cosine the angle between OA and OB.